# EPiServer, id as key in a querystring, id hijacked by url-rewriter, use rewriter for specified location?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, query-string, episerver

I have rewritten an old application that then have quite a lot of external applications that redirects to a specific url containging the ?id={someid} querystring.. however.. episerver seems to do something with the id-key.. since that's never displayed in Request.QueryStrings.AllKeys..So my guess is that epi is doing some kind of url-rewriting or something.. is there any way to get around this and be able to use the id-key for only a specific page/location?

Comment: Which EPi version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The querystring parameter id is reserved by EPiServer. You need to check it before EPi touches it.

Update: If you step up to EPi 7.5 the query parameter “ID” is no longer handled by EPi unless you register a EPiServer.Web.Routing.ClassicLinkRoute.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the IIS 7 url rewrite module to transform the id querystring key to something that will not conflict with EPiServer, as id is used for the page id in EPiServers internal url after the friendly url has been converted within the url rewrite provider.
The IIS url rewrite module would give you a chance to change this before hitting EPiServer.

You could write a regular expression to capture the id param, so you could add the following rule to your rewrite configuration

```
    <rule name="QueryString">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)id=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(.*)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}?{C:1}oldid={C:2}{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

Which would rewrite the url to /my-url-path/?**oldid=123**&another=param

More on how to implement as a rule in the IIS url rewrite module [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)